# Apply a function with a loop for in imagecollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to apply a mask to a imagecollection, I want to a apply this mask image a image, because if I apply the mask to the whole collection, I cant extract values by points.

I am using a mask of fitoprincipe, https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/wiki/Cloud-Masks

But when I apply this I can't get it to mask anything.

Outline_Trigo is a perimeter shape [Outline.shp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OLEtRQbiJOlzRaYTVfZ8zxLE6xk0jqTb/view?usp=sharing)

points is a points shape [points_all.shp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IJZSySxMCIWaAdh0SzENypTO4o_IN4uJ/view?usp=sharing)

How could I do the loop, I can't get it to work with either for or while, and I only find information about doing it with .map or .iterate.

```
// Creamos la función que nos calcula el indice del NDVI
function NDVI(entrada){
var ndvi = entrada.addBands(entrada.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']).rename('NDVI'))
return (ndvi)
}
var cloud_masks = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks');
var sentinel2function = cloud_masks.sentinel2();

// Creamos la coleccion inicial, filtramos por fechas y lugar, añadimos la banda del NDVI
var coleccion_NDVI = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
 .filterBounds(Outline_Trigo)
 .filterDate('2018-03-01','2018-03-15');
Map.centerObject(Outline_Trigo,15);
Map.addLayer(Outline_Trigo,{color: '006600', strokeWidth: 8},"Outline_Trigo");
print(coleccion_NDVI, 'Colección NDVI');

var lista=coleccion_NDVI.toList(coleccion_NDVI.size())
var i=0;
var imagen;
var longitud= lista.size().getInfo()
//var fecha;
for(var i = 0; i<longitud;i++){
  sentinel2function(i)
}


//while (i < longitud) {
// imagen = ee.Image(lista.get(i))
 //fecha=imagen.get('system:index').getInfo().substr(0,8)
 // Apply mask
 //var masked_image = sentinel2function(imagen);
// sentinel2function(imagen);
 //Map.addLayer(imagen,{},"Imagen_"+i,false)
//i=i+1;
 //Export.image.toDrive({
 //image: imagen.select("NDVI"),
 //description: "Imagen_"+i+"_"+fecha,
 //scale: 10,
 //region: trigo
 //})
//}

//var coleccion_NDVII = ee.ImageCollection(coleccion_NDVI.map(sentinel2function))
// Transform image collection of VH band into image with n bands
var timeSeries = ee.ImageCollection(coleccion_NDVI.select('B8', 'B12', 'B4')).toBands()

// Extract data for each point
var sampledReg = ee.Image(timeSeries)
      .sampleRegions({
        // Get the sample from the points FeatureCollection.
        collection: points,
        // Properties from the points collection to pass on to the sampled info
        properties: ['id'],
        // Set the scale to get Sentinel pixels in the FeatureCollection.
        scale: 30,
        tileScale: 8,
      });

// Export table as csv
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: sampledReg,
    description: 'DataRenamed',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
});

var vis = {bands:['B8', 'B12', 'B4'], min:0, max:5000};
Map.addLayer(sampledReg, vis, 'Sentinel 2 masked');
Map.centerObject(points)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a for loop instead of using the (recommended) `map()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [Client vs. Server](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server) guide in Earth Engine documentation, particularly the [Looping](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server#looping) section. It's not possible to loop over the contents of an `ee.ImageCollection` because it is a server side object, not a client-side object.

You *could* use `.getInfo()` to download the entire ImageCollection and then loop over it. However, looking at your example, you should instead use `.map()`. Here's a quick demonstration of how this could apply to your code:

```
var cloud_masks = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks');
var sentinel2function = cloud_masks.sentinel2();

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
 .filterBounds(Outline_Trigo)
 .filterDate('2018-03-01','2019-01-01');

print(collection, 'Original Collection');

var cloud_masked_collection = collection.map(sentinel2function);
print(cloud_masked_collection, 'New Collection');
```

After this, you can continue to use `.map()` to operate on each image in the collection. For example ...

```
var ndvi = function(image) {
 return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']).rename('NDVI'))
}
var collection_NDVI = cloud_masked_collection.map(ndvi)
```

Or instead of calling `image.addBands`, you could call `image.updateMask()` or `image.sampleRegions()` or any other method that operates on an image.